# Error while making flashable zip for lenovo ideapad a107

Tags: android, android-source, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

- I had downloaded the Android ICS source code from google repositories.

  - I had implemented some tweaks and successfully compiled the source code and its working fine on emulator.
  - I had decided to flash on a lenovo Ideapad a107 device.so I downloaded the device configuration from the link https://github.com/gmarkall/android_device_ideapad_a1/tree/ics.
    I was able to compile the source code for lenovo ideapad a107 device with command **make -j4**
  - But when I execute the command **make -j4 otapackage** (to make flashable zip) I am getting the following error.

  **File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 846, in 
      main(sys.argv[1:])
    File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 814, in main
      WriteFullOTAPackage(input_zip, output_zip)
    File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 416, in WriteFullOTAPackage
      MakeRecoveryPatch(output_zip, recovery_img, boot_img)
    File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 343, in MakeRecoveryPatch
      recovery_type, recovery_device = common.GetTypeAndDevice("/recovery", OPTIONS.info_dict)
    File "/home/ashwin/bin/12_APRIL_ANDROID/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 826, in GetTypeAndDevice
      return PARTITION_TYPES[fstab[mount_point].fs_type], fstab[mount_point].device
  KeyError: '/recovery'**

I am googling for almost 15 days.Posted the same question on xda-developers,android-porting group,android-platform group and many but no answer no guide.Please anyone help me in this regards.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I Resolved this issue by adding following line in recovery.fstab file

```
/recovery mtd recovery
```

Comment: specifically more accurate solution is to write custom script in releassetoos folder.But since I am not that expert guy.The above line of code worked for me.Now going to flash on actual device.